# Saving Activity state involving multiple activities. Use saveInstanceState or Preferences?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, state-saving

So I have a start game layout that is in landscape mode. When I click on `button a` or `button b`, a new activity starts depending on which button I click. When I click `button a`, I can add pictures to an `imagebutton` and edit the names of players. (I'm making a Volleyball App) Then when I go back to my start game layout and click on `button a`, all the images and textview containing the players name is back to what it was when a new game was created.

I want the info that I put in to be saved. What can I do?

Comment: SharedPreferences is a way to go :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Thanks Peshal, some help with sharedPreferences? I am a newb to this. Only started programming for android 6 months ago.

Comment: Check this out: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision depends on should the data be saved if the activity is destroyed.

Usually saveInstanceState is used to save a data when the activity is going from landscape to portrait mode (or back).

If you will use Preferences, the data will be saved permanently, even if you shut down the phone.